# Ubuntu 14.10 keeps freezing without real reason

Tags: 13.10, freeze

I have a year old ideapad laptop, I was running 14.04 for a few months without issues, it's only recently that I started encountering a lot of freezes, I would generally be browsing the internet maybe edit a file via vim or some simple tasks like that.
very annoying

Answer (score 0):

Try when switch to tty2 `ALT+F2` login and reinstall Xorg

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall Xorg
```

any change?